# Why does postgres' upper range function for a daterange return an exclusive bound?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've created a sql fiddle for this post: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7b5d7/1/0

**Question #1**

Why does inserting a record with a `daterange` that has exclusive bounds actually store a range with an inclusive lower bound and an exclusive upper bound? Why doesn't pg store them both as inclusive bounds?

**Question #2**

`SELECT upper('[2016-06-19, 2016-06-21)'::daterange)` returns `2016-06-21`. Note that `[` signifies an inclusive lower bound and `)` an exclusive upper bound.

Shouldn't selecting the upper bound return `2016-06-20`? Don't dates have have discrete intervals?

Comment: That's the way it's implemented. [From the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE): "*The built-in range types int4range, int8range, and daterange all use a canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound; that is, `[)`*"  And `[2016-06-19, 2016-06-21)` is exactly the same range as `[2016-06-19, 2016-06-20]`

Comment: Regarding question #2, the manual states that dateranges are discrete. So then shouldn't `upper` return `2016-06-20` instead of `2016-06-21`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Re **Question #1**: closed-open is the standard way to handle date ranges, with 20-25 years of history in the academic literature. See pp. 24-25 of *Bitemporal Data* by Tom Johnston, and also *Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL* by Richard Snodgrass.

But I think one of the reasons is that consecutive ranges don't have overlap. If `a` is `[May2016, Jun2016)` and `b` is `[Jun2016, Jul2016)`, they don't share any days. So they "snap together", and you don't have to worry about edge cases where they touch.

Note that one drawback (maybe) of closed-open is that you can't specify an empty range. `[May2016, May2016)` is simply a self-contradiction, whereas `[May2016, May2016]` is an instant.

Re **Question #2**: Again it could have been different, but I can think of several advantages of making `upper([May2016, Jun2016))` return `Jun2016`:

- It returns the same thing regardless of the resolution of the range.
- It is more like the mathematical meaning of an open endpoint, where it is the *only* possible answer.
- It returns what matches the "label", so arguably it is less surprising.
- It lets you easily see if two ranges "meet": `upper(a) = lower(b)`.

Also, note that in Postgres *all* time-related datatypes are discrete. There used to be an option to compile Postgres with float-based timestamps, but it is deprecated and I've never encountered it.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. I'll definitely be looking at / reading the resources you've listed.

Comment: I wouldn't buy either book just for this, but the topic of temporal databases is quite deep and fascinating. The Snodgrass book is available free here: http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html (but nicer to read in print).

Comment: Oh also: Johnston says in a footnote that he covers the rationale for closed/open more fully in his other book, *Managing Time in Relational Databases*, pp. 56-59. I haven't read that though.