# Sqlalchemy dialects DATERANGE vs. psycopg2.extras.DateRange changing bounds

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I need to change the bounds for my DATERANGE column. The default is `bounds='[)'`.

This is my current column:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import DATERANGE
booked_date = Column(DATERANGE(), nullable=False)
```

The problem is I cant do anything with the `DATERANGE()` in my example, it doesnt have any arguments and there is no documentation on this. I always thought that this `DATERANGE()` comes from `psycopg2.extras.DateRange`, but it seems its not the case, because according to the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#range-data-types) DateRange should accept these arguments:

```
class psycopg2.extras.DateRange(lower=None, upper=None, bounds='[)', empty=False)
```

How do I change the `bounds` on my example?

Where is the difference between `psycopg2.extras.DateRange` and `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import DATERANGE`?

**EDIT**

My column remains as is. But I need to add daterange datatypes to the db by using `DateRange` from `psycopg2`:

```
un_daterange = DateRange(undate_lower.date(), undate_upper.date(), bounds="[]")

new_booking = UserBooksRoom(booked_date=un_daterange, date_added=datetime.today(),
booking_type='correction')
```

The problem here is if I select 21.01.2019 - 27.01.2019 `un_daterange` will look like this: `DateRange(datetime.date(2019, 1, 21), datetime.date(2019, 1, 27), '[]')`, which is correct, but in the DB it looks like this: `[2019-01-21,2019-01-28)`. The upper bound is 1 day higher, why? I thoguht `'[]'` means include lower and upper bound.

Also while checking wether the booking is available:

I select the date 19.01.2019 - 21.01.2019, it will correctly tell me that this date is not available because 21.01.2019 is the lower bound.

If I select 27.01.2019 - 30.01.2019 it will also be correct.

If I select 28.01.2019 - 30.01.2019 it will tell the date is available.

So all in all It WORKS correctly, `date)` simply means `date - 1 day`. But why is it this complicated? And why `bounds="[]"` does not work?

**EDIT**

I checked again and bounds does work. Without bound="[]" it would look like this in the DB: `[2019-01-21,2019-01-27)` and selecting 27.01.2019 - 30.01.2019 would tell me that it is possible and that would be wrong.

Basically when displaying the range information to a user with `.lower` and `.upper`, you need to subtract 1 day from the upper bound.

Comment: The edits are covered for example here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123680/strange-upper-behaviour-for-dateranges-in-postgresql, and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953786/why-does-postgres-upper-range-function-for-a-daterange-return-an-exclusive-boun. In short, Postgresql uses a canonical closed-open form for `int4range`, `int8range`, and `daterange`. So `bounds="[]"` does work, just not exactly the way you expected. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that

- `psycopg2.extras.DateRange` represents a Postgresql `daterange` **value**. You define bounds on a *per value basis*.
- `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.DATERANGE` is *from SQLAlchemy*, as should be clear from the qualified name, and represents a Postgresql `daterange` **type**, as used in a `CREATE TABLE` statement etc. It does not care about the bounds of the **values** you store in a column having this type.

To recap: use `DATERANGE` when creating models and `Table`s in SQLAlchemy to define the type of a column, use `DateRange` to represent values that can be stored in such a column, if using Psycopg2 as the DB-API driver.

Comment: Ah okay! I got the concept. Thanks again.

Comment: Of course the range operators then muddy the waters a bit, since you can treat a column/instrumented attribute as an expression having a `daterange` value when building queries... But then again that mapping is more of a SQLA to Postgresql, not SQLA to Psycopg2 range object. The important thing is to form a mental model of when you're working with SQL expression objects (those that you pass to SQLA queries etc. in order to compile SQL) and when with Python objects, and the boundaries between them.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I made an edit, because I still dont fully understand a thing, but at least the code works perfectly now. I just want to fully undstand this.