# Why are exclusive lower bounds converted to inclusive?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

Given the following code, is there a way to turn off Postgres converting the lower bound to inclusive, that is going from `(date` to `[date+1`?

```
CREATE TABLE test (range daterange NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO test (range) VALUES ('(2001-01-01,infinity)');
SELECT * FROM test -- returns [2001-01-02,infinity)
```

Comment: Just to add `infinity` does not seem to be a factor, using `INSERT INTO test (range) VALUES ('(2001-01-01,2002-01-01)');` results in `[2001-01-02,2002-01-01)`

Comment: Both represent the same range, so what's the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37956049

Comment: It was unexpected before I understood the behavior. Also it makes the inserted value asymmetric with the selected value which changes the testing strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the docs [Ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INCLUSIVITY):

> The built-in range types int4range, int8range, and daterange all use a canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound; that is, [). User-defined range types can use other conventions, however.

So the answer is no.